# How to get the output of a query run on database

Tags: perl, dbi

When we execute the query, we can see the error messages with the help of

```
print OUT "$DBI::errstr";
```

But how can we get the result of the query on successful execution, like

```
table TRN_STLMNT_ created
```

Comment: I think OP wants to get the message which database prints to STDOUT when you manually run a query on it.

Comment: Essentially you want to know if the query was successful, right?

Comment: I need the complete statement, Example if the table is created successfully then <code> table TRN_ST created </code>

Answer (score 0):

Having written a few scripts using DBD::mysql and DBD::Sybase database drivers with the DBI module, I found that the best way to figure out if your execution was successful is to enable the raising of errors on you DBI database handle and if no error was raised then you would then manually print out your "table TRN_ST created" message.

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=test;host=localhost",
                     "joe", "joe's password",
                     {'RaiseError' => 1 });
```

http://search.cpan.org/~capttofu/DBD-mysql-3.0008/lib/DBD/mysql.pm
http://search.cpan.org/~mewp/DBD-Sybase-1.15/Sybase.pm